# How to migrate AWS API gateway from one account to another account using aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-api-gateway

I have tried to export AWS API gateway from my source account using boto3
find my code below

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['aws', 'apigateway', 'get-export', '--parameters', 'extensions="integrations"', '--rest-api-id', 'xxxxx', '--stage-name', 'dev', '--export-type', 'swagger', '--region', 'us-east-1', '--accept', 'application/json', 'api_gateway_test.json'])
```

But after execute this code i m getting the following error,

> An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the GetExport
> operation: Invalid stage identifier specified

How to solve this issue?
Note: I tried with different stage-name, but same error showing

I want to export API gateway as a JSON file which will save in my local machine, after that i will import same JSON into my another aws account
I am following this AWS link
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-migrate-accounts-regions/

Comment: i m trying different concept, i m ok with aws cli or boto3

Answer (score 0):

Since you are importing `boto3` to your python code, you should be using [get_export](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.get_export) from `boto3`. There is no reason to do that using AWS CLI if you already have `boto3`.

Comment: hi @Marcin Yes, i have added boto3 code as well. can you check now?

Comment: @Udhayakumar Now your question is different then you originally posted. For the new issue of "what to do with json" you should make new question.

Comment: yes understand, edited my question

Comment: posted as a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72432455/how-to-use-exported-json-for-api-gateway-migration-from-one-a-c-to-another-a-c-u